# Categorical x-axis errorbar plot in matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, categorical-data, errorbar

I'd like to plot errorbars with categorical X variable. The error bars (upper and lower) are on Y values only.

For example, the code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = ["4", "10", "50"]
y = [3, 2, 1]
yerr = np.matrix([[1.5, 1.1, 0.9], [1.3, 1.2, 0.8]])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.errorbar(x, y, yerr=yerr)
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

gives the following error:

```
ValueError: In safezip, len(args[0])=3 but len(args[1])=1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you get has nothing to do with categorical axis.

You just cannot use a matrix. Use a numpy array,

```
yerr = np.array([[1.5, 1.1, 0.9], [1.3, 1.2, 0.8]])
```

or simply a list, there is no need to use numpy here,

```
yerr = [[1.5, 1.1, 0.9], [1.3, 1.2, 0.8]]
```

Comment: Yeah, I realized later it wasn't related to the categorical axis. This is a simple example. In the actual code, I have to use numpy. That's why I had it there.